# number of folders in a directory (recursive)

Tags: bash, find, directory

I would like to print the number of folders (recursive, excluding hidden folders) in a given CWD / current directory.  What command, or series of commands can I use to ascertain this information?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "***a*** given root directory"? A Unix/Linux system has ***one*** root directory. (2) Have you made an attempt to solve this yourself? What have you tried? (Hint: How would you *identify* the folders in a given folder, and how would you count things?)

Comment: base dir?  directory containing other directories (which in turn contain other directories)?  yes, i've made an attempt, but `wc` won't work because it counts files.  would `ls` work with a for loop in a bash script or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What about symlinks to a directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will find the number of non-hidden directories in the current working directory:

```
ls -l | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

**EDIT:**

To make this recursive, use the `-R` option to `ls -l`:

```
ls -lR | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need this to be recursive; is there a modification that would comply? EDIT: this doesn't seem to omit hidden dirs

Comment: If it is not omitting hidden directories, do you have an `alias` set for `ls` that is listing hidden directories by default?

Comment: Good point.  I had one in my `bash_profile`.  Thanks for the recursion update as well.

Comment: Be cautious with the -R flag for ls. Check the output without the `wc -l` pipe, because I think ls -lR adds blank lines and dir names between files, which might throw off your count.

Comment: @transistor1 Good point.  In this case however the `grep "^d"` displays only the entries which have a `d` at the beginning of the line.  Blank/non-directory lines should not be displayed without the `wc -l` or counted with the `wc -l`.

Comment: @TimothyMartin that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

In the GNU land:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf . | wc -c
```

elsewhere

```
find . -type d ! -name . -printf . -prune | wc -c
```

In bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob
count=0
for dir in *; do
  test -d "$dir" || continue
  test . = "$dir" && continue
  test .. = "$dir" && continue
  ((count++))
done
echo $count
```

Comment: `-printf` is GNU specific, while `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` are now found in  a few other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

`echo $(($(find -type d | wc -l) - 1))` is one way (subtract 1 from the wc -l to remove the current dir).  You can tweak the options to [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to find different things.

`echo $(($(find -type d -not -path '*/\.*'  | wc -l) - 1))` - to exclude the [hidden dirs](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211)

As I mentioned in the comments, the heart of this expression is really `find -type d`, which finds all directories.

Note this finds all subfolders as well - you can control the depth using the `-maxdepth` flag.

Comment: that's interesting - so, there's no built in command to do something like this?

Comment: @jml - Someone else likely has something simpler, but `find` is my go-to for file finding & counting.  The "meat" of this ugly expression is really just `find -type d`, which finds any directories.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `tree` command?

```
tree -d /path/to/maindir| awk END{print}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
(){echo $#} *(N/)
```

Recursively:

```
(){echo $#} **/*(N/)
```

Add the `D` glob qualifiers if you also want to count hidden directories.

POSIX equivalents:

```
ls -p | grep -c /
```

(add the `-A` option to `ls` for hidden ones)

Recursively:

```
LC_ALL=C find .//. ! -name . \( -name '.*' -prune -o -type d -print \) |
  grep -c //
```

Or

```
LC_ALL=C ls -Rqn . | grep -c '^d'
```

To include hidden ones:

```
LC_ALL=C find .//. ! -name . -type d | grep -c //
```

or:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -ARqn . | grep -c '^d'
```

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type d -not -path '.' -printf 0 | wc -c ;`

Recursively find all directories (-type d) within current directory (find .) that is not (.) directory and print 0 for each directory found. Then `wc -c` counts the number of characters (0) from the previous command output.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the first part of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167245/116858